# Prove that if $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}n(f(\frac{1}{n})-f(0))=L$ then $f'(0)=L$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$f$ is differentiable. Prove that if $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}n(f(\frac{1}{n})-f(0))=L$ then $f'(0)=L$.

I tried L'Hopital: $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}n(f(\frac{1}{n})-f(0))=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac {f(\frac{1}{n})-f(0)}{\frac{1}{n}}$, but it didn't get me far...

Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Comment: $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: Let $h = \frac{1}{n}$ in your limit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't you solve it already?

"I tried L'Hopital: $lim_{n→∞}n(f(\frac{1}{n})−f(0))=lim_{n→∞}\frac{f(\frac{1}{n})−f(0)}{\frac{1}{n}}$, but it didn't get me far."

Isn't the definition of a derivative by using limits:

$lim_{h→0}\frac{f(x+h)−f(x)}{h}$

So for your case, just let $h = \frac{1}{n}$

Comment: yeah, didn't notice something so trivial!